# Why is this TopoJSON rendered so small with D3? (Simple example)

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, geojson, topojson

I'm trying to do something really simple. I have a GeoJSON file of all the congressional districts of New York and I simply wanted be able to view it in my SVG element. I converted it to TopoJSON and tried to follow [this tutorial](https://bost.ocks.org/mike/map/) (except I tried using the new updated d3 v4 API). The main problem is that the map, I think, does get rendered but it is very small. If I try to scale it up then I lose sight the map entirely.

Here is my html and d3 js:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>NY State Districts Demo</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Hello</h1>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.10.2/d3.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/topojson/3.0.2/topojson.js"></script>
        <script>
            /* JavaScript goes here */
            var width = 960, height = 1160;
            var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg").attr("width", width).attr("height", height);

            d3.json("./ny_bounds.json", function(error, ny){
                if(error) return console.error(error);
                console.log(ny);
                svg.append("path")
                    .datum(topojson.feature(ny, ny.objects.ny_bounds))
                    .attr("d", d3.geoPath().projection(d3.geoAlbersUsa()));
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

[Here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0peT1bdqVG4N3pFVUc4Z0F6bm8/view?usp=sharing) is a link to the TopoJSON in question.

I will admit that I don't have much knowledge on d3 and geo/topoJSON but I'm just stuck at this point. If anyone has any resources where I can learn more about these subjects that would be great too. But as I said before the primary problem is that the map is too small and I can't seem to center/scale it.

Thanks in advance for helping.

Comment: Hey man, im working on a similar type of project for an org I'm starting. We should link up off stackoverflow so we can help each other out when possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are projecting data with a projection that is intended to project points across the entire US, including Hawaii and Alaska. New York will be a small portion of this projection area. Scaling any map projection will zoom in towards the center of your projection - d3 does not know to zoom in to a particular location, so as you zoom in, New York will fall off the edge of your projection.

As an AlbersUsa projection is a composite projection (to allow inclusion of Alaska, Hawaii), it is actually several Albers projections combined on one plane.  Because of its composite nature, it is harder to manipulate. To keep things simple, I would recommend using a plain Albers projection. This also allows you to tailor the projection to New York state.

An Albers projection has two standard parallels, these are parallels of the projected plane that intersect the surface of the globe (it is a conical projection). The standard parallels should be located in the area of interest, one in the lower half and one in the uppper (as these are the parallels that intersect the globe, distortion is minimized along these parallels). For New York state, parallels like 41 and 44 degrees north could work.

You also need to center the projection. To do so you need the geographic center of your area of interest. The center of New York is 42.954 degrees north and 75.527 degrees west (-75.527 degrees East). To center a Albers projection, rotate on the x(by the inverse of the longitude as we spin the globe under us) and center on the y. Altogether this looks like:

```
d3.geoAlbers()
  .center([0,42.954])
  .rotate([75.527,0])
  .parallels([41,44])
  .translate([width/2,height/2])
  .scale(k) // scale factor
```

Now you need to make sure your geoPath uses this projection ( yes, you need to specify the translate if your width or height is not the default 960x500 as this centers the center of your projection). The scale zooms in with larger numbers, a factor of 2000 should get you started.

Comment: Thanks for the information and the detailed response on how you derived the numbers. Do you happen to have a resource that you refer to when finding the correct parallels for an area?